# Pushing arrays based on each row inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, optimization

Based on my code I want to push each row's inputs to each array. If it is row1, it should push all the input values of row 1 to array `a1`. The second row's inputs should be pushed to array `a2` and so on.

This is mainly for performance optimization of my code since the rows of my real code are 20+ and I am trying to do it like below but without success.

I want to be able to know each row's data  (for validation purpose)

```js
$('#check').click(function(event){
event.preventdefault;
  var a1=[];var a2=[];
  $("[id^=row]").find("td input").each(function(i) { a[i].push(this.value); });
  $('#output').html('<h4>Pushed arrays:</h4>a1: ['+a1 +'] <br/> a2: ['+a2+']');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="check">Check Values</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: you have some code errors: 1st in this line you forgot to close the string expression, should be like this: `$('#output').html('<h4>Pushed arrays:</h4>a1: ['+a1 +'] <br/> a2: ['+a2+']');` and 2nd you can't do `a[i]` and expect it to find a varibale of `a2` or `a1`, instead it will try to look inside variable `a` at position `i`. you can do it this way:  ``[`a${[i]}`].push(this.value);``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this.

I tried to stay as close to your code as possible to not scare you off JavaScript

```js
$('#check').click(function(event){
  event.preventdefault;
  var a=[];
  $("[id^=row]").each(function() { // for each row
    var idx = a.length; // find how many entries in a
    a[idx]=[]; // add a new array
    $(this).find("td input").each(function(i) { a[idx].push(this.value); }); // fill the array
  });  

  var output = ""; // initialise a string
  for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) { // loop over a's items
    output += "a["+i+"]:"+a[i].join(","); // join each array with comma
    output += "<br/>";
  }  
  $('#output').html('<h4>Pushed arrays:</h4>'+output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="check">Check Values</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `$.map` to create a nested array.  It seems as if you want to have a lot of rows.  So, I would recommend a 2d array instead of individual variables to avoid repetitive code.  With a 2d array you can loop through each row; with individual variables you'd have to manually rewrite the same code for each row.

```js
$('#check').click(function(event){
  event.preventdefault;
  var serialize = [];
  $("#myTable tr").each(function () {
    serialize.push($.map($(this).find("input"), function (ele) {
      return ele.value;
    }));
  });
  console.log(serialize);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
<tr>
          <td>1</td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
         <td><input  type="text" size="4"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
<button id="check">Check Values</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Okay i need to have each row's inputs seperately for validation

Comment: @GragasIncoming If it is easier to separate it into individual variables, simply do `var a1 = serialize[0], a2 = serialize[1]`.

Comment: How should i edit when nothing is empty and when the value is 1 or 0 to push ?

Comment: @GragasIncoming I'm a little confused by your phrasing.  It will add whatever is in each column to the array.  It will add whatever is inside the textboxes.

Comment: okay one more problem. I need to convert each array into string, is that possible to do `serialize[2].join("");` ?

Comment: Personally, I'd use `JSON.stringify(serialize[2])`.  Optimally, I'd use JSON.stringify on the the variable serialize itself.  (You can use join, but it isn't going to look right if you have empty values).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this :

```js
$("#check").click(function() {
  // collect data
  var rows = $("tr").get().map(r => (
    $("input", r).get().map(i => i.value)
  ));
  // print data
  $("#output").html("<h4>Pushed arrays:</h4>" + rows.map((r, i) => (
    "a" + (i + 1) + ": [" + r.join(", ") + "]"
  )).join("<br>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="0" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="4"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="check">Check Values</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

### Hints to understand the above code

JQuery API and MDN doc :

- http://api.jquery.com/get/#get
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Demo of `join`, `map` and arrow functions :

```
xs = ["A", "B", "C"]
// ["A", "B", "C"]
"[" + xs.join(", ") + "]"
// "[A, B, C]"
xs.map(function (x) { return parseInt(x, 16); })
// [10, 11, 12]
xs.map(x => parseInt(x, 16))
// [10, 11, 12]
xs.map((x, i) => x + i)
// ["A0", "B1", "C2"]
xxs = [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
// [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
xxs.map(xs => "[" + xs.join(", ") + "]")
// ["[A, B]", "[C, D]"]
xxs.map(xs => "[" + xs.join(", ") + "]").join("<br>")
// "[A, B]<br>[C, D]"
```

Comment: You just converted `35+` lines of code into `2` congratz. I'll need to study how it works because it is only 2 lines but it is way more complex to understand :)

Comment: How could i store each row's data into a variable? (mainly to parse that variable into php)

Comment: @GragasIncoming Answer updated. Too long to explain the code line by line, but I believe a couple of hints can help as well. You can send the data to PHP using JSON format, see `JSON.stringify()` (JS) and `json_decode()` (PHP).

Comment: @GragasIncoming By the way, as surprising as it may sound my goal was NOT to make the code short, my goal was to make it readable. When you are not familiar with something, it doesn't mean that it's inherently hard to understand :-P Get familiar with `map`, you will never go back ;-)